# How to save bucket names to a string and add new ones after that to an array

Tags: arrays, append, office365, power-automate

i have planner buckets (Tasks, in progress, Backlog) and I want to create a new Bucket depending on elements in a SharePoint list.

But I can't save the bucket names to an array and then add the missing value e.g. like "on hold" and the go trough the array again. It always set my array to blank again.

Maybe you can help me. Here is my PowerAutomate Flow so far:

[image: Save to Array or String]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a couple of Select actions to create two arrays which you can use for the comparison. With a Filter Array you can find the ones which are missing. The output of that Filter Array can be used to loop through and create the missing buckets.

Below is an example of that approach.

*1. In both Select actions the Map field is switched to text mode to only get Arrays with values (without keys)*

*2. In the Filter Array this is used in the From*

```
body('Select_-_SharePoint_Items')
```

*3. And this is the expression used in the advanced mode*

```
@not(contains(body('Select_-_Existing_Buckets'), item()))
```

[image]